# return values of particular key if a string is present in an array

Tags: sql, arrays, json, postgresql

I run a simple select * query that returns an output like this:

```
[{
  "polarity": "0.0",
  "magnitude": "2.0",
  "score": "0.5",
  "entities": [{
    "name": "Taubenkot",
    "type": "OTHER",
    "mid": "",
    "wikipediaUrl": "",
    "numMentions": "1",
    "avgSalience": "0.150263"
  }, {
    "name": "Lösung",
    "type": "OTHER",
    "mid": "",
    "wikipediaUrl": "",
    "numMentions": "1",
    "avgSalience": "0.145794"
  }, {
    "name": "Busbahnhof",
    "type": "LOCATION",
    "mid": "",
    "wikipediaUrl": "",
    "numMentions": "1",
    "avgSalience": "0.108006"
  }, {
    "name": "Stadt",
    "type": "LOCATION",
    "mid": "",
    "wikipediaUrl": "",
    "numMentions": "3",
    "avgSalience": "0.079928"
  }, {
    "name": "Taubenplage",
    "type": "OTHER",
    "mid": "",
    "wikipediaUrl": "",
    "numMentions": "2",
    "avgSalience": "0.072326"
  }, {
    "name": "Rutschgefahr",
    "type": "OTHER",
    "mid": "",
    "wikipediaUrl": "",
    "numMentions": "1",
    "avgSalience": "0.070839"
  },
{
    "name": "Meike Böschemeyer",
    "type": "PERSON",
    "mid": "/g/11btlnnjgf",
    "wikipediaUrl": "",
    "numMentions": "1",
    "avgSalience": "0.00451"
  }]
}]
```

"Entities" is an array. I want to select all rows where the "type" = "LOCATION" is present in one of the entities values. In this case, I want to return the "name" value of that entity entry as a new column NAME.

something like "select .... AS NAME". How can I achieve this?

Comment: mysql or postgres both are different also mysql doesn't support arrays

Comment: also postgres also needs to unnest the array to search it see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/functions-array.html

Comment: unclear if this is supposed to represent a query result with polarity, magnitude, etc columns or a single json string column

Comment: all other columns can be ignored. I want to consider the values of entities only @ysth

Answer (score 0):

First flatten the JSON field. See [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cXK3k99Bg7q2NinYXtAFFP/0)

```sql
select l ->> 'name' as "Name", 
      (l ->> 'avgSalience')::numeric as "avgSalience"
      -- , other expressions
from the_table 
cross join lateral json_array_elements(j -> 0 -> 'entities') l
where l ->> 'type' = 'LOCATION';
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option to flatten the JSON array is to use a JSON path expression:

The following returns the names as rows.

```
select l.item ->> 'name' as name
from the_table t
  cross join jsonb_path_query(t.the_column, '$.entities[*] ? (@.type == "LOCATION")') as l(item)
```

Another option is to return the names as a single JSON array:

```
select jsonb_path_query_array(t.the_column, '$.entities[*] ? (@.type == "LOCATION").name') as names
from the_table t
```

This assumes that the column is defined with the data type `jsonb` (which it should be). If it's not you need to cast it: `the_column::jsonb`

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/X4T2cfqg?hide=4)